# useState setter no updating the value of its state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to save the time in which my function start is called but after `setStartTS()` is called `startTS` still null. I'm not sure if requestAnimationFrame is introducing any type of bug here, any ideas of where the issue may be

```
const Chrono = () => {
  const [startTS, setStartTS] = useState(null);
  const [diff, setDiff] = useState(null);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

  const start = () => {
    if (startTS) {
      return;
    }
    const tic = +new Date();
    setStartTS(tic);
    setIntervalId(requestAnimationFrame(tick));
  };

  const tick = () => {
    const tock = +new Date();
    const timePassed = tock - startTS;
    setDiff(timePassed);
    setIntervalId(requestAnimationFrame(tick));
  };

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: I assume that this is a custom hook? If so, its name must start with `use`. Also, am I correct to assume that `start` and `tick` are returned when this custom hook is called?

Comment: Not it is not, Chronos is a React Component, I'm only using useState()

Comment: I see. I also notice a typo there - your are creating a constant called `tic` but then you try to use `tick`. Additionally, `requestAnimationFrame` cannot be used like that, it should receive some callback. Why are you using `requestAnimationFrame` anyway? Can you use `useEffect` instead?

Comment: Do you call `start` function somewhere in the `Chrono` component?

Answer (score 2):

React's hooks provide a api called useEffect. You may need this to call `start()` function when the component mount.

```
const Chrono = () => {
  const [startTS, setStartTS] = useState(null);
  const [diff, setDiff] = useState(null);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

  // --> add effect
  useEffect(() => {
    start();
  });

  const start = () => {
    if (startTS) {
      return;
    }
    const tic = +new Date();
    setStartTS(tic);
    setIntervalId(requestAnimationFrame(tick));
  };

  const tick = () => {
    const tock = +new Date();
    const timePassed = tock - startTS;
    setDiff(timePassed);
    setIntervalId(requestAnimationFrame(tick));
  };

  return (...)
}
```

For more detail about useEffect api, please check out [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Hey, @Ponleu the thing is that `start` is gonna be called when the user presses a bottom, instead useEffect() will call the function as soon as the component renders.